# How to make my model optional for sequelize method - typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Here is my model -

```
import { BuildOptions, DataTypes, Model, Sequelize } from "sequelize";

import { IDBUserAttributes } from "./shared/db-table";

interface UserModel extends Model<IDBUserAttributes>, IDBUserAttributes {}

class User extends Model<UserModel, IDBUserAttributes> {}

type UserStatic = typeof Model & {
  new (values?: object, options?: BuildOptions): UserModel;
};

const UserFactory = (sequelize: Sequelize): UserStatic => {
  return <UserStatic>sequelize.define("users", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(320),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(26),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
  });
}

export {
  UserModel,
  User,
  UserFactory,
  UserStatic,
}
```

The `IDBUserAttributes` got all the fields for type checking.

Here is the `index.ts` file -

```
import { UserFactory } from '../user';
import { MovieFactory } from '../movie';
import { FavoriteMoviesFactory } from '../favoriteMovies';

import * as sequelize from "sequelize";

const instantiateObj = {
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DB_NAME,
    username: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PWD,
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
}

const dbConfig = new sequelize.Sequelize(instantiateObj.database, instantiateObj.username, instantiateObj.password, {
        port: Number(instantiateObj.port),
        host: instantiateObj.host,
        dialect: "mysql",
        pool: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000,
        },
    }
);

const User = UserFactory(dbConfig);
const Movie = MovieFactory(dbConfig);
const FavoriteMovies = FavoriteMoviesFactory(dbConfig);

export {
    dbConfig,
    User,
    Movie,
    FavoriteMovies,
}
```

I would like to use the `User.create() or User.build()` without all of the fields.
Right now i can't do that because of the `IDBUserAttributes` I'm getting the error -

```
Argument of type '{ email: string; username: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IDBUserAttributes'.
  Type '{ email: string; username: string; password: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IDBUserAttributes': id, createdAt, updatedAtts(2345)
```

I went to - https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html#usage-of--code-sequelize-define--code-

And saw that -

// Some fields are optional when calling UserModel.create() or UserModel.build()

```
interface UserCreationAttributes extends Optional<UserAttributes, "id"> {}
```

How can I apply that to my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the optional fields with an union:

```
interface IDBUserCreationAttributes extends Optional<IDBUserAttributes, "id" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt"> {}

class User extends Model<IDBUserAttributes, IDBUserCreationAttributes> {}
```